# Showing certain divs on multiple checkbox selection is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a section with seven checkboxes, they are Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday & Saturday. I also have two other sections with other checkboxes they are Morning Session Section & Evening Session Section.

Now what I need to do is if someone selects any day from Sunday to Friday in sessionDays then it should display both Morning session section and Evening Session Section. But if someone selects Saturday or Sunday checkbox, it should display only Morning Session Section.

I have tried doing that using below code, but it only shows Morning & Evening Section in Monday selection. It doesn't display anything if other days are selected.

```js
jQuery(function($){
      //Assigning DIVs & Fields to variable
      
        var sessionDays = $('.sessionDays');
          var sessionSunday = $('#sessionSunday');
          var sessionMonday = $('#sessionMonday');
          var sessionTuesday = $('#sessionTuesday');
          var sessionWednesday = $('#sessionWednesday');
          var sessionThursday = $('#sessionThursday');
          var sessionFriday = $('#sessionFriday');
          var sessionSaturday = $('#sessionSaturday');
        var sessionTime = $('.sessionTime');
          var sessionMorning = $('.sessionMorning');
            var eightnine = $('#eight-nine');
            var nineten = $('#nine-ten');
            var teneleven = $('#teneleven');
            var eleventwelve = $('#eleven-twelve');
          var sessionEvening = $('.sessionEvening');
            var fourfive = $('#four-five');
            var fivesix = $('#five-six');
            var sixseven = $('#six-seven');
            var seveneight = $('#seven-eight');

      //Hide required DIVs
      sessionEvening.hide();
      sessionMorning.hide();
      sessionDays.hide();

      $("#selectSessionType").change(function(){
        if( !$(this).val() ) {
          sessionDays.hide();
        } else {
          sessionDays.show();
        }
      }).change();

      $(sessionMonday, sessionTuesday, sessionWednesday, sessionThursday, sessionFriday).change(function() {
          if( sessionMonday.is(':checked') == true || sessionTuesday.is(':checked') == true || sessionWednesday.is(':checked') == true || sessionThursday.is(':checked') == true || sessionFriday.is(':checked') == true ) {
              sessionMorning.show();
              sessionEvening.show();
          } else if ( sessionSaturday.is(':checked') == true || sessionSunday.is(':checked') == true) {
            sessionMorning.show();
          } else {
            sessionMorning.hide();
            sessionEvening.hide();
          }
      });
  });
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="age underEighteen">
  <h3>Under 18 Class Selection</h3>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="selectSessionType">Choose Session Type <span>*</span></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="selectSessionType">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Select Session Type</option>
        <option value="beginners">Beginners</option>
        <option value="hourly">Hourly</option>
        <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <div class="days sessionDays">
      <label>Select Session Days</label>
      <p class="text-muted">Select the specific days you want to come for training.</p>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="sessionSunday">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionSunday">
          Sunday
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="sessionMonday">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionMonday">
          Monday
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="sessionTuesday">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionTuesday">
          Tuesday
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="sessionWednesday">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionWednesday">
          Wednesday
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="sessionThursday">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionThursday">
          Thursday
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="sessionFriday">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionFriday">
          Friday
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="sessionSaturday">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionSaturday">
          Saturday
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <div class="sessionTime">
      <div class="sessionMorning">
        <label>Select Session Time</label>
        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Morning Session</p>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="eight-nine">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="eight-nine">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="nine-ten">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="nine-ten">9:00 AM - 10:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="ten-eleven">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="ten-eleven">10:00 AM - 11:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="eleven-twelve">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="eleven-twelve">11:00 AM - 12:00 PM</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sessionEvening">
        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Evening Session</p>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="four-five">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="four-five">4:00 PM - 5:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="five-six">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="five-six">5:00 PM - 6:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="six-seven">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="six-seven">6:00 PM - 7:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="seven-eight">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="seven-eight">7:00 PM - 8:00 PM</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/humanware/Lpmv5vyv/

Comment: It seems that all of the content in the code you posted is hidden. I think the "user info" inputs are not included. Can you create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: This is different from what you asked for in the JS chatroom - did you want only Evening to show for Sunday and Saturday, or only Morning to show?

Comment: @showdev here is the working example:  https://jsfiddle.net/humanware/Lpmv5vyv/

Comment: @TylerH Hey Tyler, Welcome. I am trying to show Morning & Evening Session Section if someone selects Monday to Friday & only Show Morning session if someone selects Saturday or Sunday from SessionDays Checkbox.

Comment: @MilanUptech Thanks for clarifying. We've edited your post a bit to reflect these clarifications!

Comment: @TylerH Thanks for your support to the newbie like me sir. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well as per your requirement I used map in jquery and assigned the value to checkbox, here is code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var sessionDays = $('.sessionDays');
    var sessionMorning = $('.sessionMorning');
    var sessionEvening = $('.sessionEvening');
    //Hide required DIVs
    sessionDays.hide();
    sessionMorning.hide();
    sessionEvening.hide();

    $("#selectSessionType").change(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            sessionDays.hide();
        } else {
            sessionDays.show();
        }
    }).change();
    $(".sessionDays").change(function () {
        sessionMorning.hide();
        sessionEvening.hide();
        $('.form-check-input:checked').map(function () {
            if (
                this.value == 'Monday' ||
                this.value == 'Tuesday' ||
                this.value == 'Wednesday' ||
                this.value == 'Thursday' ||
                this.value == 'Friday') {
                sessionMorning.show();
                sessionEvening.show();
                exit();
            } else if (this.value == 'Saturday' ||
                this.value == 'Sunday') {
                sessionMorning.show();
                sessionEvening.hide();
            } else {
                sessionMorning.hide();
                sessionEvening.hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();}
```

Edit HTML:

```
<div class="age underEighteen">
<h3>Under 18 Class Selection</h3>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="selectSessionType">Choose Session Type <span>*</span></label>
        <select class="form-control" id="selectSessionType">
            <option selected="selected" value="">Select Session Type</option>
            <option value="beginners">Beginners</option>
            <option value="hourly">Hourly</option>
            <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <div class="days sessionDays">
            <label>Select Session Days</label>
            <p class="text-muted">Select the specific days you want to come for training.</p>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Sunday" id="sessionSunday">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionSunday">
                    Sunday
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Monday" id="sessionMonday">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionMonday">
                    Monday
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Tuesday" id="sessionTuesday">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionTuesday">
                    Tuesday
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Wednesday" id="sessionWednesday">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionWednesday">
                    Wednesday
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Thursday" id="sessionThursday">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionThursday">
                    Thursday
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Friday" id="sessionFriday">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionFriday">
                    Friday
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Saturday" id="sessionSaturday">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionSaturday">
                    Saturday
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <div class="sessionTime">
            <div class="sessionMorning">
                <label>Select Session Time</label>
                <p style="font-weight:bold;">Morning Session</p>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="eight-nine">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="eight-nine">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="nine-ten">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="nine-ten">9:00 AM - 10:00 AM</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="ten-eleven">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="ten-eleven">10:00 AM - 11:00 AM</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="eleven-twelve">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="eleven-twelve">11:00 AM - 12:00 PM</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sessionEvening">
                <p style="font-weight:bold;">Evening Session</p>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="four-five">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="four-five">4:00 PM - 5:00 PM</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="five-six">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="five-six">5:00 PM - 6:00 PM</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="six-seven">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="six-seven">6:00 PM - 7:00 PM</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="seven-eight">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="seven-eight">7:00 PM - 8:00 PM</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's almost working for me but I need to carry values for calculation from value attribute. and when you select saturday it's displaying Morning section but if you select other with saturday it's not showing evening. but it's working fine for sunday.

try here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpmv5vyv/1/

Comment: hi @MilanUptech I have just added exit() function under first if condition below the sessionEvening.show() function now it will work properly according to your requirement. you can see here also: https://jsfiddle.net/raviook/zzjj832b/3/

Answer (score 1):

I added a weekend class to the checkboxes of friday and saturday and a weekday class to the other days.

**EDIT:** HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <div class="days sessionDays">
        <label>Select Session Days</label>
        <p class="text-muted">Select the specific days you want to come for training.</p>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input weekend" type="checkbox" value="" id="sessionSunday">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionSunday">
            Sunday
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input weekday" type="checkbox" value="" id="sessionMonday">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionMonday">
            Monday
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input weekday" type="checkbox" value="" id="sessionTuesday">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionTuesday">
            Tuesday
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input weekday" type="checkbox" value="" id="sessionWednesday">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionWednesday">
            Wednesday
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input weekday" type="checkbox" value="" id="sessionThursday">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionThursday">
            Thursday
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input weekday" type="checkbox" value="" id="sessionFriday">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionFriday">
                Friday
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input weekend" type="checkbox" value="" id="sessionSaturday">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="sessionSaturday">
                Saturday
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <div class="sessionTime">
        <div class="sessionMorning">
            <label>Select Session Time</label>
            <p style="font-weight:bold;">Morning Session</p>
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="eight-nine">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="eight-nine">8:00 AM - 9:00 AM</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="nine-ten">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="nine-ten">9:00 AM - 10:00 AM</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="ten-eleven">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="ten-eleven">10:00 AM - 11:00 AM</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="eleven-twelve">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="eleven-twelve">11:00 AM - 12:00 PM</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sessionEvening">
            <p style="font-weight:bold;">Evening Session</p>
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="four-five">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="four-five">4:00 PM - 5:00 PM</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="five-six">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="five-six">5:00 PM - 6:00 PM</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="six-seven">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="six-seven">6:00 PM - 7:00 PM</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="seven-eight">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="seven-eight">7:00 PM - 8:00 PM</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then this should be all the jQuery:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.sessionMorning').hide();
    $('.sessionEvening').hide();

    $('.weekday, .weekend').on('change', function () {
        var weekdayChecked = false;
        var weekendChecked = false;
        $('.weekday, .weekend').each(function (index, input) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('weekday') && $(this).is(':checked')) {
                weekdayChecked = true;
            }
            else if ($(this).hasClass('weekend') && $(this).is(':checked')) {
                weekendChecked = true;
            }

            if (weekdayChecked) {
                $('.sessionMorning').show();
                $('.sessionEvening').show();
            }
            else if (weekendChecked) {
                $('.sessionMorning').show();
                $('.sessionEvening').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('.sessionMorning').hide();
                $('.sessionEvening').hide();
            }

        });
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4h7z5ovj/1/

Comment: Hi Thijn, it would be more helpful if you included all the code here, rather than only some of it. When JSFiddle goes down (which has happened before), this answer becomes less useful if half the code is hidden away there.

Comment: Also, see OP's latest clarification comment under the question - they want to show only Morning for both Saturday and Sunday, not just Saturday. I will edit the question to clarify it there, as well. Your code currently follows the original question's test of both Morning and Evening showing on Sunday.

Comment: I will add the html, now. I added the weekend class to friday instead of sunday, will change it with my update.

Comment: it's working in jsfiddle but not in my site because my WordPress site has jquery version 1.12.4 and jsfiddle is using jquery 3. is there any solution?

Comment: Does it give an error?
I changed jQuery to 1.12.4 and it still works:
https://jsfiddle.net/4h7z5ovj/10/